# Modern reference for Andre Weil's 'Sur les courbes algébriques et les variétés qui s'en déduisent'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I'm currently interested in the cardinality of the set of values of a polynomial over a finite field.

I found a paper

> Saburo Uchiyama, *Sur le Nombre des Valeurs Distinctes d'un Polynome a Coefficients dans un Corps Fini*, Proceedings of the Japan Academy **30**, Issue 10 (1954) p. 930–933, doi:[10.3792/pja/1195525873](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195525873), [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195525873).

In the paper, the author uses some theorem of Weil on an asymptotic formula of the cardinality of the zero set of an absolutely irreducible polynomial $f^{\ast}(u,v)=\frac{f(u)-f(v)}{u-v}$.

So I want to study 'quickly' Weil's theorem on this occasion. But the 1948 book of Weil 'Sur les courbes algébriques et les variétés qui s'en déduisent' ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/3895353)) seems to be out of print and might not be modern.

I have a little familiarity with the first 3 chapters of Hartshorne.

I hope someone can recommend a reference. Thank you.

Comment: Hartshorne Exercise 1.10 of Chapter V, Section 1.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Thank you very much for your comment. I think the exercise gives a roadmap. May I ask one more reference that might be more comprehensive please?

Comment: You may find a sketch, with some details, of the proof of Hasse-Weil bound for the number of ${\mathbb F}_q$-rational points on a smooth projective curve defined over the finite field ${\mathbb F}_q$ in the notes posted on the following link: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~rohanjoshi/2019/11/25/the-riemann-hypothesis-for-curves-over-finite-fields/